# Why am I getting "Jest encountered an unexpected token" when using detox with expo-updates?

Tags: node.js, expo, ts-jest, detox, babel-jest

I want to use [expo-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-updates) package with detox and jest, however I keep getting the following error:

```
 FAIL  test/e2e/starter.test.ts..
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    ...
    
    Details:

    <Redacted>/node_modules/expo-updates/build/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export * from './Updates';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

      1 | import { expect, device, by } from 'detox'
    > 2 | import * as Updates from 'expo-updates'
        | ^
      3 |
      4 | describe('Example', () => {
      5 |   beforeAll(async () => {
```

I have this `jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  rootDir: '..',
  testMatch: ['<rootDir>/**/*.test.ts'],
  testTimeout: 120000,
  maxWorkers: 1,
  reporters: ['detox/runners/jest/reporter'],
  globalSetup: 'detox/runners/jest/globalSetup',
  globalTeardown: 'detox/runners/jest/globalTeardown',
  testEnvironment: 'detox/runners/jest/testEnvironment',
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!expo-updates)'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest',
  },
  verbose: true,
}
```

and I added to `babel.config.js`

```
presets: [
  ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }],
  '@babel/preset-typescript',
]
```

So what else can I do?

Using these versions:

- ts-jest: 29.0.3
- babel: 29.3.1
- expo-updates: 0.14.7